# Spring 406 with a custom Configurer

Tags: java, spring

I recently added `jackson-dataformat-xml` to the classpath, and magically spring started sending XML instead of JSON if the `Accept` header wasn't precised in the request. Since I'm dealing with spaghetti legacy code adding the header to all requests is not an option, I added a custom content negociation filter :

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation (ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    super.configureContentNegotiation(configurer);
    configurer
            .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
}
```

However, this backfired for a request like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> edit(...) throws ApiException {
    .... // returns an inputstream
}
```

Where I get a 406 error. If I remove the default content type, it works fine but then I get xml for other requests. How can I configure both?

Comment: Try setting the `produce` parameter of your `@RequestMapper`.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "edit", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/json"})

Comment: It doesnt change anything unfortunately